# How to show all arrays without numbers etc

Tags: php, html, oop, pdo

Another little question,
I forgot to add this in my previous question,

How do I display all messages, stored in my database?

I now have this code;

```
<?php
require('./dbconfig.php');
$userid = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$query = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT bericht FROM tijdlijn WHERE auteurid=:uid");
$query->execute(array(':uid' => $userid));

$tijdlijn=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r ($tijdlijn[0]['bericht']);

?>
```

But the problem is, this only shows the first column of 'bericht', and I want it to let it show all messages, not just one.

Greetz,

Sahin.

Comment: Loop over them instead of selecting just the first one.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do this? I'm not yet familiar with PDO.

Comment: has nothing to do with pdo. just loop over the resulting array. foreach ($tijdlijn as $tijd) { echo $tijd['bericht']; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing related to `PDO`. You might wanna do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tijdlijn); $i++)
  print_r ($tijdlijn[$i]['bericht']);
```

Or in a better way:

```
foreach ($tijdlijn as $tijd)
  print_r ($tijd['bericht']);
```